# Counting Biz days for each row of database

Tags: sql, date, impala

I have a table with each row containing a start and end date with timestamp format and need to filter them by the number of business days between the start and end date.

Based on some of the solutions posted here, I created a separate table with all days and marked them with a boolean field like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_holiday (h_date TIMESTAMP, is_holiday BOOLEAN)
```

Is it possible to write a query that filters by count days between start_date and date_date that has _is_holiday as False?

My database is Impala.

Comment: Why have a table called holiday with a column called "is holiday"? Isn't that a given?

Comment: It's a table that keeps the status of each date, it's either holiday or not, on the other table, assume, tbl_main we have start_date and end_date, count of biz days between start_date and end_date for each row of tbl_main is needed

Comment: Well, you could also just have the holidays in a list, count the number of days between your two dates and subtract the number of actual holidays (e.g. some `COUNT(*) FROM tbl_holiday  WHERE h_date BETWEEN ...`). Then you don't have sparse (mostly unuseful) noise in your holiday list. Not the end of the world, but you don't need it per se.

Comment: It's a super complex query and I was hoping to come up with a custom Function and then use that to get the count, instead of running the query, however, the Impala has a different syntax and the way it works on SQL Server doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You would typically join the original table with the holiday table with inequality conditions on the start and end date, aggregate, and finally filter in a `having` clause by the sum of business days against your target value:

```
select t.id, t.start_date, t.end_date
from mytable t
inner join tbl_holiday h on h.hdate between t.start_date and t.end_date
group by t.id, t.start_date, t.end_date
having sum(cast(is_holiday as int)) = :no_of_business_days
```

Comment: Thank you @GMB, I'm getting an error: ParseException: Syntax error... Then 0 ELSE 1 END, Encountered: : Expected CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, ...

Comment: I have an id field in db, do I still have to use start_date and end_date in GROUP_BY clause? Tried with/wo, same error

Comment: @MehdiZare: I updated the query, please give it another try.

Comment: still the same error, I also tried h.is_holiday IS TRUE

Comment: @MehdiZare: I changed the query a little, if you may try. PS: are you sure that `is_holiday` is of datatype `boolean`?